# What parses command line args into args[] on Windows?

Tags: java, c#, c, windows, command-line-arguments

On Windows, the [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) win32 function is used to create a new process. The signature for this function takes a pointer to the "command line" `lpCommandLine`, so the command line is passed as a single string.

Every language that I'm familiar with (C, C++, C#, Java) allows a `main` function that accepts an array of strings. So, somewhere between CreateProcess and `main` there must be something that is parsing `lpCommandLine` and turning it into `args[]`.

Where does this parsing code live? Is it part of the OS (inside `CreateProcess`), or is it part of each languages "runtime" (code that runs inside the new process before `main` is called)?

Comment: The rules appear to be here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/17w5ykft(v=vs.85)

Comment: @MarkPflug, the operating system has to parse the command line at least enough to determine what command to run in the (allowed) case that the `lpApplicationName` parameter is null.  Of course, given that Microsoft writes a lot of its own language runtimes, and that it is notorious for blending layers, I'm not sure that the question is in fact inquiring about a meaningful distinction.

Comment: This is wildly dependent on the called-application. CreateProcess forwards the command line; the process entrypoint itself is utimately responsible for discerning the argument breakup. Ex: WinMainCRTStartup and wWinMainCRTStartup are the default entrypoints for MSVS-built C or C++ applications built as narrow or unicode respectively. Both are capable of breaking apart the cmd  line arguments from the CreateProcess arguments.

Comment: It is up to the application and whatever language it is written in.  It is not the role of CreateProcess nor the OS to _"[parse] lpCommandLine and turning it into args[]."_.   _[Tell me more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)_

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think the distinction is quite meaningful, in fact. If the args are parsed by the OS, then the behavior should be consistent regardless of language used. If the parsing is done by the language runtime itself, then the behavior might be different depending on how the language, or even the *version* of the language, happens to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime startup code linked into the program you're running.  For C, for example, it's crt0.c.

The created process begins execution in user mode at some declared entry point, which is not `main`. It is the C runtime that calls `main`.

Back when I was a Windows C programmer, the C runtime source code was included in the SDK.

Comment: If we don't use `lpApplicationName` to pass an explicit executable path, `CreateProcessW` parses the command line for the executable, with special handling for space and double quote. If there's no quoting, it consumes spaces until it finds an executable. For example, it may find `C:\Program Files\spam\eggs.exe`, but not if `C:\program.exe` exists.

Comment: If an application's runtime library of choice doesn't parse the command line, it can manually call [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) with the Unicode command line from [`GetCommandLineW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew). This function is part of the Windows shell, shell32.dll.